# Why does the 'delegate' option in the Connections Inspector not show for custom classes?

Tags: xcode

I have defined a delegate protocol in my custom class this way:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)myMethod;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    id<myProtocol> delegate;   
}   
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<myProtocol> delegate;
@end
```

Now in Interface Builder, I drag an NSObject on to the 'Objects' area.
Set its class to MyClass.

Why does the connections Inspector not show 'delegate' option (like it does for framework classes below)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that it is an [`IBOutlet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitConstantsReference/Reference/reference.html) like so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)myMethod;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    IBOutlet id<myProtocol> delegate;   
}   
@property(nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id<myProtocol> delegate;
@end
```

---

From [UIKit Constants Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitConstantsReference/Reference/reference.html):

> - **IBOutlet**
>     Identifier used to qualify an instance-variable declaration
>     so that Interface Builder can synchronize the display and connection
>     of outlets with Xcode. Insert this identifier immediately before the
>     variable type in any variable declarations.